# How can I export X509Certificate in ASN1 format using bouncy castle in java?

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, asn.1

How can I export a `X509Certificate` in ASN.1 format?
I found how to export to **DER** and **PEM**, using `.cer` extension, but I can not find how to export to ASN.1 format. Can anyone help me?

This is my PEM:

```
JcaPEMWriter pemWrt = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter(path + ".cer"))
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(loadCertificate);
pemWrt.writeObject(certificate);
pemWrt.flush();
pemWrt.close();
```

This is my DER:

```
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(loadCertificate);
FileOutputStream fileWrite = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + ".cer"));
fileWrite.write(certificate.getEncoded());
fileWrite.flush();
fileWrite.close();
```

Comment: What sort of output are you expecting? ASN1 stands for "**Abstract** Syntax Notation 1". DER is a concrete encoding for ASN.1, and PEM is a binary-to-text encoding which can envelope DER.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that **ASN.1** is not a format *per se*, it's a [description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) that **defines** a structure, and [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail) is just one way to format these defined structure. (Many cryptography standards use **ASN.1** to **define** their data structures, and **PEM** or [**DER** (Distinguished Encoding Rules)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) to **serialize** those structures.)

So, **PEM** and **DER** are just 2 different ways to write information that was defined by **ASN.1**. You can export something to **PEM** or **DER**, but there's no such thing as *"export to ASN.1 format"* (because **ASN.1** is not a format).

The `.cer` extension is just a file extension for digital certificates, but this certificate can be either in **PEM** or **DER** (it doesn't matter, and the extension won't change).

So, when you use `JcaPEMWriter`, you are **already** creating the file in **PEM** format. And when you use `certificate.getEncoded()`, you are **already** writing the bytes in **DER** format.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have java.security.cert.X509Certificate certificate and and I have to export it to PEM or DER, but ASN.1 formatted. (defined in ASN.1) Do you know how I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "asn1 formatted"? ASN.1 just **defines** the structure (what fields it has, if it's mandatory, valid values, etc). If the certificate was created, it means that **it already has** the structure defined by the [respective ASN.1 definition](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280). PEM and DER are the formats used to write an ASN.1 structure, but ASN.1 itself is not a format.

Comment: Maybe you're talking about asn1Dump? http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/asn1/util/ASN1Dump.html - just call `dumpAsString` passing the certificate. Not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is very old question, but I found below OpenSSL command which covert Cert DER/PEM format data in to ASN1.

> `openssl asn1parse -in Cerificate.pem -inform PEM`

Hope this will help someone in future.